# Creating SF points from multiple lat longs

Tags: r, r-sf

```
library(sf)

DT <- data.frame(
  lat1=c(-26.3, -27.1, -26.8),
  long1=c(27.3, 28.5, 28.2),
  lat2=c(-26.5, -26.9, -27.2),
  long2=c(28.3, 27.5, 28.1)
)

DT$p1 <- st_geometry(st_as_sf(DT,coords = c("lat1","long1")))
DT$p2 <- st_geometry(st_as_sf(DT,coords = c("lat2","long2")))
```

I have a data frame with 2 sets of lat/longs which I would like to convert to points.

```
DT$p1 <- st_geometry(st_as_sf(DT,coords = c("lat1","long1")))
```

gives the expected result, but

```
DT$p2 <- st_geometry(st_as_sf(DT,coords = c("lat2","long2")))
```

gives me the same result as DT$p1.

[image]

If I change the order of those two statements, both will give the points of (lat2,long2)

[image]

How can I create a df with multiple points per row?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `st_geometry` creates a sticky column that is used to identify the geometry of an sf object. Using `st_as_sf` with an already present and active geometry column will ignore any other attempt to specify a geometry column. In order to create a second geometry column we can temporarily drop the sf class (using (as.data.frame).

```
library(sf)

DT = data.frame(
  lat1=c(-26.3, -27.1, -26.8),
  long1=c(27.3, 28.5, 28.2),
  lat2=c(-26.5, -26.9, -27.2),
  long2=c(28.3, 27.5, 28.1)
)

DT = st_as_sf(DT, coords = c("long1","lat1"), remove = FALSE)
DT$p2 = st_as_sf(as.data.frame(DT), coords = c("long2","lat2"))

DT

# Simple feature collection with 3 features and 4 fields
# Active geometry column: geometry
# geometry type:  POINT
# dimension:      XY
# bbox:           xmin: 27.3 ymin: -27.1 xmax: 28.5 ymax: -26.3
# epsg (SRID):    NA
# proj4string:    NA
#    lat1 long1  lat2 long2           geometry                 p2
# 1 -26.3  27.3 -26.5  28.3 POINT (27.3 -26.3) POINT (28.3 -26.5)
# 2 -27.1  28.5 -26.9  27.5 POINT (28.5 -27.1) POINT (27.5 -26.9)
# 3 -26.8  28.2 -27.2  28.1 POINT (28.2 -26.8) POINT (28.1 -27.2)

st_geometry(DT)

# Geometry set for 3 features 
# geometry type:  POINT
# dimension:      XY
# bbox:           xmin: 27.3 ymin: -27.1 xmax: 28.5 ymax: -26.3
# epsg (SRID):    NA
# proj4string:    NA
# POINT (27.3 -26.3)
# POINT (28.5 -27.1)
# POINT (28.2 -26.8)
```

Also, note that the correct coordinate specification is x,y hence long,lat not lat,long

Comment: You should always always always specify a projection too using a crs code ideally, so 4326 would likely be the correct one, but check...